# when i join objects, it goes into wireframe and deletes modifiers

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view, edit-mode

https://gyazo.com/a2660538e1065da70101e2a7083c0eb7

this happens every time i try to join a object. I select the two I want to join, and then I join them, and they become wireframe & un-subdivided. This is for any objects I try to do this with, and if its more than 2 that i join, it will close out and crash entirely.

what should I do to fix this?

and these are also my settings if this helps seeing what is wrong
[image: settings]

Comment: i assume that you have changed your shortcuts and that at least two operators have the same shortcut.

Comment: Hi, i am not sure if this https://prnt.sc/599_JKdXezdN and  https://prnt.sc/44YDJvHsbwNu if this helps, i dont know

Comment: pls show a screenshot for searching for j as key-binding